# What are the differences when installing Visual Studio 2017 x64 vs. x86?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am looking at the MS web page for downloading VS 2017 Enterprise.  It has a dropdown for x64 or x86?  Since VS itself is an x86 application, what are the differences in the other tools that are going to be installed x64 and x86?

Is it versions of SQL, IIS Express or other build tools?  Looking for a list of what versions each installer installs.  Or is to do with just which type of Windows you install to (32 vs. 64 bit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, they will give you the same setup bootstrapper, which in turn will install the same packages.  Because VS includes tooling for 64-bit development, it's offered as x86 or x64, but that's an internal classification detail which causes the dropdown to offer both.